# Custom validation provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, provider

Have a trouble with displaying errors near fields from own validation provider. Provider works and displays errors in summary validation block, but not near fields.

Provider is added to list of providers in **Global.asax**

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FFvalidator());
```

**FFvalidator** represents that code:

```
public class FFvalidator : ModelValidatorProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<ModelValidator> GetValidators(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        if(metadata.ContainerType == typeof(RegisterViewModel))
        {
            return new ModelValidator[] { new UserRegPropertyValidator(metadata, context) };
        }
        if(metadata.ModelType == typeof(RegisterViewModel))
        {
            return new ModelValidator[] { new UserRegValidator(metadata, context) };
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidator>();
    }
}
```

Validator is inherited from **ModelValidator**
Looks like that:

```
public class UserRegPropertyValidator : ModelValidator
{
...
}
```

Validation method (method of **UserRegPropertyValidator**) is shown below:

```
        public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
        {
        RegisterViewModel u = container as RegisterViewModel;
        if(u != null)
        {
            switch (Metadata.PropertyName)
            {
                case "UserName":
                    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z-,]{1,35}$");
                    if ( !rgx.IsMatch(u.UserName) )
                    {
                        return new ModelValidationResult[]
                        {
                            new ModelValidationResult {MemberName="UserName", Message="Кроме букв, допустимы только символы - и ,"}
                        };
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
```

But the trouble is that, AJAX validation doesn't work. ASP validation works well, for example an email binder show the error near the field like needed.

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean _AJAX validation_? (the only client side validation that uses ajax is a `RemoteAttribute`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke html-helper Html.ValidationMessageFor creates a block with error after the focus on the field is lost. It's asp-built capability - we get error near field without sending form. My trouble is that errors from built-in validation provider are showed, but errors from my custom provider - no

Comment: I know exactly what `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` is and does. Read my previous comment - there is no such thing as _AJAX validation_!

Comment: @StephenMuecke probably, i don't understand the validation mechanism clear. I'll write another words
I have a field Email and if it's value doesn't contain @, after the focus is lost i'll get the message that field is not correct. As far as i understand, that message i generated by built-in validation provider in ASP, queried by ajax and shown near the field.

Comment: It works well, but my solution needs a custom validation provider that will validate other fields. I have implemented that provider and it returns errors to frontend only by ValidationSummary() and after sending form. I need to get errors from that provider after loosing field's focus. 

I have found the info about RemoteAttribute. Is it the only way of generating ajax-errors for frontend?

Comment: You have all your terminology wrong.I assume you mean _client (not AJAX) validation doesn't work_ and _Server (not ASP) validation  works well_? It not clear what you are wanting to achieve and you have not shown the relevant code (I assume this is in a class that implements `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`)? What you have shown is handled correctly out of the box using a `[RegularExpression]` attribute so what is it that your trying to do with this code?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you have understood me right. Server validations work (i can get actual errors from custom provider on server), but client - not (actual errors are shown after sending form in ValidationSummary block). 
I've updated the post, and add all the code structure that i'd intergarated

Comment: But this will not give you any client side validation. MVC client side validation works by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` script reading the `data-val-*` attributes in the html generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods, and then adding rules to `jquery.validate.js`.

Comment: Its not clear what your wanting to validate - all you have shown is something that can be handled by using a `[ReqularExpression]` attribute applied to the property. If you want something hat cannot be handled by the built in validation attributes, then you can create your own - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke my goal was to create a class which has all validation rules in one place because it's more flexible than writing all requirements near properties of a viewmodel. Have read info about Remote() attibute and i'm pleased. I have impletendet one controllet with validation methods and use that. Thank you!

Comment: It is simply crazy to be wasting resources by using `[Remote]` for something that can be done on the client by using validation attributes that implement `IClientValidatable`. If you doing that, then your not understanding the basics.